# Programmatically get the folder location

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this VB code which on debugging gets me the following location

> C:\Users\AUpadhyay\AppData\Roaming\Sterling Ultra Precision\Power
>   Suite\2.7.0.0

The VB Code is

```
AppPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData).ToString
```

I was trying to reach the same directory using the below C# code but the output is

> C:\Users\AUpadhyay\AppData

The C# code is

```
AppPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)).ToString();
```

What would be the line of code to get the same directory address ?

Comment: Did you try Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() ?

Comment: Try this: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`Application.UserAppDataPath`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.userappdatapath(v=vs.110).aspx) would be your solution.

It's accessible from both VB.NET and C#, and it returns:

```
C:\Users\[Your user name]\AppData\Roaming\[Your company name]\[Your product name]\[Your product version]
```

---

**Result from C#:**

[image: Application.UserAppDataPath in a MessageBox]

Comment: let me know if you could check before me :)

Comment: @Apoorv : Of course :). -- By the way I just updated the link, I accidentally used the wrong one before.

Comment: you have always been a helping hand :) Thanks

Comment: @Apoorv : Thank you :). I take it you've tested it aswell?

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the `Roaming Folder that is present inside AppData folder`, Then the rest of folders are Known, So you can use [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to concat them; Consider the code :

```
string AppPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

string requiredPath=Path.Combine(AppPath,@"Sterling Ultra Precision\Power Suite\2.7.0.0");
```

Comment: how do I reach here Sterling Ultra Precision\Power Suite\2.7.0.0 ? That one VB line of code is giving the full address

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the current directory in c#

`string AppPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;`

Comment: I need to access the Roaming Folder that is present inside AppData folder

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "FileYouWant.foo")
```